# Books for virtualization - technical explanations needed

Tags: virtual-machine, computer-science, virtualization, cpu-architecture

I want to learn virtualization basics inside out. All the books in top results of amazon are too superficial and are only meant for managers, ie people who only need to have a vague idea of what it is all about. I want to understand it inside out and from the basics.

**Please DONT suggest virtualization for dummies. That book is superficial.**

**I want the core concepts only, that is how virtuazlization works behind the scenes. I am NOT looking for books to set up any virtual machine software like vmware, hyper-v etc.**

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are no books covering this subject (how a VMM actually works).

The way I gained my knowledge was by reading whitepapers and research-papers, and once I was past that, looking at QEmu/KVM and VirtualBox.

A nice overview can be found here:
http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/VMware_paravirtualization.pdf‎

A deeper paper (often refered to in other paper) can be found here:
https://www.vmware.com/pdf/asplos235_adams.pdf

After reading those, you should have gotten a nice "vocabulary" about VMMs, and you should be able to google your way to other papers by using VMM specific vocabulary such as "Hardware assisted VMM page faults", and so forth.

Comment: All of your links are broken. :(